# How to specify which data members are changed by a method?

Tags: c++, methods, constants

Suppose you have a class like this (pseudocode):

```
class Worker
{
    int state;
    int something;
    int data;

    void prepareWorker()
    {
        state=get_some_value(data,something);
        something=get_another_value();
    }
    int doActualWork()
    {
        data*=5;
        something+=data;
        return state+data*something;
    }
public:
    Worker() : something(235), data(1) {}
    int doSomeWork()
    {
        prepareWorker();
        return doActualWork();
    }
};
```

Here `state`, `something` and `data` denote some sets of variables, not single ones. Both `doActualWork()` and `prepareWorker()` aren't `const` methods, but there's something which may be useful for code readers to know beforehand: `doActualWork()` only changes `data` and `something`, while `prepareWorker()` only changes `state` and `something`. I'd like to be able to force `prepareWorker` have `data` as `const`, while `doActualWork` to have `state` as `const`.

One option would be to make the methods `const` and just pass the variables they change by reference as arguments. But, as I mentioned, the variables here denote some potentially large sets of variables, so passing them all would be ugly and useless since the functions already have `this` pointer to know their address. Also in this case the methods have little advantage of being methods of the class.

Another option I can think of is to write an adapter class, which would e.g. privately inherit from `Worker` and provide access to all the variables with appropriate permissions. But this seems somewhat much work for small benefit.

Is there any better trick to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why not just document it?

Comment: @NathanOliver because the compiler ignores comments. If the code is later changed, the compiler won't force whoever changes it to update the comment.

Answer (score 3):

There may be other qualities of your situation that would affect this advice, but I would do this:

Create separate classes for `data` and `state` and either a struct or a class for `something`. The Data object gets a `doActualWork()` method and `state` gets a `prepareWorker()` method. Both methods accept a (const?) reference to the `something` struct or class.

Then the `doActualWork()` and `prepareWorker()` methods of `Worker` become super simple delegators, and by delegating to a contained class the access restrictions become obvious and enforced by the compiler.